# RouterLink does not navigate to a component on click but navigates after loading other component in same module

Tags: angular, routes

In my Angular 8 application I have following routes.

**Public routing module:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent }
];
```

**User routing module:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile', component: UserProfileComponent },
  { path: 'purchase-agreement', component: PurchaseAgreementComponent },
  { path: 'purchase-credit', component: PurchaseCreditComponent },
  { path: 'purchase-confirmation', component: PurchaseConfirmationComponent },
  { path: 'purchase-thankyou', component: PurchaseThankyouComponent },
  { path: 'expenditure-report', component: ExpenditureReportComponent },
  { path: 'subscriptions', component: SubscriptionComponent },
  { path: 'subscribe', component: SubscribeComponent }
];
```

**App routing module:**

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'startup',
    component: StartupComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/core-modules/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule),
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'startup',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

**Header Html where I have put routerLinks to navigate to `account` route and it's children:**

```
    <mat-menu #accountMenu [overlapTrigger]="false" yPosition="below">
        <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/account/profile']">
            <mat-icon>person</mat-icon><span>My Profile</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/account/purchase-agreement']">
            <mat-icon>credit_card</mat-icon><span>Purchase Credits</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/account/expenditure-report']">
            <mat-icon>timeline</mat-icon><span>Expenditure Report</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/account/subscriptions']">
            <mat-icon>card_membership</mat-icon><span>Subscriptions</span>
        </button>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="logout()">
            <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>Logout
        </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

**App Module Code:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

// Helper Classes
import { JwtInterceptor, ErrorInterceptor, LoaderInterceptor } from 'app/_helpers';

// Feature Modules.
import { PublicModule } from 'app/modules/core-modules';

// Shared Functionality Modules.
import { MaterialElementsModule, SharedModule } from 'app/modules/generic-modules';

import { AppRoutingModule, mainRoutedComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent, FooterComponent } from 'app/components';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    mainRoutedComponents
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule,
    MaterialElementsModule,
    PublicModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Problem:**

After login, I am taken to startup component, where header component is visible. And I click on my profile link and ***it does not load***. But when I click on any other route/ link below it, I am being able to navigate to those components.After navigating to working components again I click on my profile from header. This time I am being take to profile component.

This is the console error I am getting when I try to navigate to my `profile` component after login.

[image: error on console]

Kindly provide some insight about this error. How is it can be solved?

Comment: Seems like the issue is not related to your routes, please check your component, I think it's related to some service which redirecting it again to the same link

Comment: i am afraid, there is not service involve at all that redirecting it to a startup component

Comment: Please try to type code or errors instead of posting photos. It is barely visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, after login when you are trying to navigate to profile for very first time than Account Module is not loaded that is why URL Path is not completed and you redirect to the startup due to this route

```
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'startup',
    pathMatch: 'full'   }
```

You have to make sure that your account module is loaded first